# What is JRules? BRMS?

Tags: jrules

What is "business rules"? Please explain with some example.

> Businees logic is core logic to build
>   the application for the requirements.

But what is business rules?

Answer (score 3):

BRMS = a set of tools to edit and execute business rules
JRules = a BRMS solution like JBoss rules, Blaze advizor, and much more

You want to use BRMS to externalize the business logic from the application.
It is the same as a database which is there to externalize data.

A business rule is atomic and represent a part of the business logic.
E.g:
"if the age of the applicant is less than 18 then reject the application"

BRMS is composed of:
- a rule repository (filesystem or DB)
- a developper (like Eclipse) and a business user (non technical) interface (web)
- an environment to execute the rules
You use BRMS in order to create a Decision Service.
It can be "callable" in J2SE, J2EE, EJB, Web Service, MDB, ...

Hence the businees rules which are part of a Decision Service (ruleapp/ruleset in JRules) can be called by various application.
The real advantage of a Decision Service.
Think of it like when a BPM needs to make a decision, rather than code the condition and actions in the application itself then make a call to a DS to have the answer, hence the decision.

It will takes you nothing more than 1 hour to create a dummy DS and call it from a BPM application such as Tibco Business Works.

Another definition of Business rules is that it is the result of a business policy implementation.
Business policy: "A good customer should be reward for the end of the year"
The Business Analyst job is to extract the rule from this statement and hence end up with rules like that:
"if the status of the customer is GOLD and the amount of the shopping cart of the customer is greater than £5,000 then set the status of the client to PLATINUM"

When you create the rule you have to ask yourself a lot of question like:
What about SILVER and BRONZE status? Are all the threshold covered by rules? and so on...


A Decision Service can potentially contain several thousands of business rules
For example: Some for validation, some for eligibility, some for quotation and so on...
Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your last sentence regarding TAG. But simply speaking, Business Rules are the rules which drive your business logic. For example in the banking domain - if the account balance is between this and this account status will be such and such, if the balance falls below such and such value, status will be something else and it will trigger some workflow like sending mail/email to the customer etc. This is just an example.

To isolate the business rules from the core application for reasons like better maintenance, separation of concern and allowing non-developers like subject matter experts to author and maintain the business rules the BRMS evolved. BRMS stands for Business Rule Management System. The piece of software which contains business rules. JRules is one such BRMS. Your application talk to BRMS to get the business rule information.

Comment: Thanks for your response. you said example right.. how brms will work in that situation.  
there is no tag for jrules here. i dont have permissions to create it. That's why wanted to add for discussion.

Comment: Please be clear what you want to ask. 
How Brms will work in that situation - What situation you want to ask?
There is not tag for jrules here - Give some context where you found the sentence "Please create a TAG on Jrules". If you found that in any requirement doc and they are talking about jsp tag then you must  either create a taglib or use any existing one. Check the JRules documentation. Are you talking about JSP tag? Please elaborate.

Comment: Also please add Jrules and BRMS tag to your question. That way JRules people are more likely to see your question and respond

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to see this in action with JBoss Business Rules Management System (BRMS) then you might like to try this repeatable demo:

http://www.schabell.org/2012/06/jboss-enterprise-brms-bpm-made-simple.html

It uses a simple walk through business process to visually demonstrate Rules integration (a Rules call is made from the process) to decide the path to take in the business process.

Hope you enjoy it. :)